# Access SQL Server on Azure VM via SQL Server Management Studio on my local Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine

I'm sure this is out there somewhere but I can't find it and my brain hurts.

I have a VM on Azure. It has SQL Server running on it. I can access it locally on the VM no problem but I would like to manage it from my dev computer via SQL Server Management Studio.

Is this possible and what creds would I use? the VM Login?

Thanks,
R

Comment: 1. Do you have SQL Server Authentication mode (or mixed mode) enabled as the authentication type?  2. Do you have the proper port (1433) open to allow incoming connections both on the VM and the network method it is using?  3. Recommend directing this question to serverfault.com.

Comment: 1 & 2, no but can do no problem. But I don't know what server to put in the box when connect to server comes up in sqlserver managment studio.  3.  Uh ok, not familiar with it but if I have no luck here I will.  Thanks,
r

Comment: Gotcha.  When you go to your Azure Portal, there should be a `DNS Name` that you setup for the VM when you uploaded/set it up.  That's the name to connect to the machine and any listening services it has running (such as SQL Server).  The authentication for SQL Server will be handled by SQL Server, not Azure or the VM or anything like that.  So it depends on the authentication setup in SQL Server.  As far as 3. goes, it's another StackExchange website very similar to StackOverflow for more IT-related questions.  You can transfer your account over there from here if you've never used it before.

Comment: use the cloudapp.net URL that you gave your VM

Comment: Great. Thank you both.  I will do that soon as I eat something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to complete all of the following to achieve what you want:

- Add a TCP endpoint for that VM on port 1433 - public & private (you can change the public port if you will).
- Configure the SQL Server Instance to listen to TCP.
- Enable the incomping TCP port 1433 in the local FireWall rules of the VM.
- Enable mixed mode authentication on the SQL Server
- Make sure your ISP does not block outgoing port 1433 (a common practice for most of ISVs since [2003' SQL Slammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Slammer)) - this is overridable with custom Public port for your TCP endpoint.

Than you will be able to connect to the SQL Server in the Azure VM using your local SSMS.

Comment: The previous commentors got me home but you have listed all the steps nicely so ill give you the bump. The one step they missed was poking a hole in the firewall. Thank you all.

Comment: Please note the public endpoint port cannot be 1433. Please see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154100.aspx

Comment: So if 1433 is blocked? How do we connect to the DB via SSMS or app, I am currently facing that problem and followed all the above steps. I checked the port of the DB in configurations, the port is still 1433 there!!!

Comment: change the public port and use that one from SSMS.

Comment: It should be noted that the article linked above by @PaulBrown has  been updated since his posting date, & port 1433 along with the other ports described in the article is now considered valid & no longer being blocked.  We tested this in our environments earlier this year & now today again to prove that Microsoft's earlier position has been reversed, fixed or clarified further for Azure VMs.

Comment: Note that if you are using a named instance then SQL Server will default to using dynamic ports.  In this scenario you will have to configure SQL Server to use a specific port, as per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx).

Comment: One think that helps me:
It started to work when I set specific port for TCP/IP protocol.
So open SQL Server Configuration Manager, find TCP/IP protocol for your instance, open Properties and set port to 1433 in IPAll section.

Answer (score 4):

Faced this issue with Azure VM, I can't connect to SQL server.
Completed all steps described in answer above but didn't get success..

It started to work when I set specific port for TCP/IP protocol.

So open SQL Server Configuration Manager, find TCP/IP protocol for your instance, open Properties and set port to 1433 in IPAll section.

Comment: I was also following all steps and I could not connect to my Azure VM's SQL Instance. Adding the exact port in the IPAII section worked. Thanks alot.

Comment: Needed this to work, on azure VM with SQL Server Express 2017.
Thank you very much!!  =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I should change was: 
 click on the VM in AzurePortal --> SQL Server configuration --> Change SQL Connectivity to public

then it works for me!

Answer (score -3):

Instead of SSMS you can also use Powershell to check connectivity with SQL server on Azure VM. The detailed powershell script is at the following link -

http://sanganakauthority.blogspot.in/2014/02/connecting-to-sql-server-virtual.html

This saves you from the installation of SSMS on the machine from which you wih to connect to SQL server virtual machine.