# End points option is not available in Azure Virtual Machine settings

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created a virtual machine on Azure with windows server 2012 and I have hosted SQL server in that machine. Now I am unable to connect that sql server through internet so I verified few of the blogs on defining end point for sql server port.

I have followed setps provided in following post with no luck...
[Access SQL Server on Azure VM via SQL Server Management Studio on my local Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202811/access-sql-server-on-azure-vm-via-sql-server-management-studio-on-my-local-machi)

When I look at my VM settings I did not find "end points" section and hence I am unable to connect to sql server from outside network.

So please help me to connect sql server via internet.

[image]

I have also tested inbound rules of my Network Security Group and it has sql server port defined in "Inbound Security Rules", please look at below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful information in below post which explained about configuring VM to allow connection from public network.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect/

And one more problem I noticed is "Configuring Sql Server with named instance", And connectivity problem got resolved after I configured SQL Server with default instance.

Thanks,
Vasu Ravuri.